# Is the Bitlocker encryption key used on HD same for USB?

Tags: encryption, windows, bitlocker

With Bitlocker, is there only one "master key" that is used to encrypt/decrypt **for both HD and USB data?**

I saw this article today which talks about sniffing the encryption key to get access to Bitlocker data on an HD. https://www.hackster.io/news/thomas-roth-breaks-microsoft-s-bitlocker-in-under-a-minute-with-a-4-raspberry-pi-pico-6ac738e6ec77

However, there is no mention of Bitlocker used on USB sticks. So I was wondering, if a hacker is able to get obtain the encryption key AND if the same key is used for both HD and USB encryption, then can this hack can be used to decrypt "Bitlocker protected" USB data as well?

1. Does anyone know if the same key is used in both areas (HD and USB)?
2. Is my thinking, albeit a high level, reasonably correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would be ridiculously insecure. Besides, removable storage needs to be decryptable on multiple computers, each of which might (or might not) have fixed drives encrypted with Bitlocker as well; it wouldn't make and sense for there to be a single key that a computer uses for each drive. Each volume - not even just each physical drive - has a unique encryption key. The numeric "recovery password" is also unique for each volume. (Technically it's not literally impossible for them to collide, since they're both random, but the expected time before that would happen dramatically exceeds the expected lifetime of the universe, because the entropy is quite high.) Furthermore, if you "turn Bitlocker off" (decrypt the drive) and then turn it on again, it'll generate a new encryption key each time, for each volume.

You can, of course, use the same "PIN" (in quotes because you can and should, with a slight tweak, use a normal passphrase instead) on multiple drives. However, the PIN (like all other means of decrypting the drive, including the "recovery password" and the flashdrive-stored unlock key) has nothing to do with the actual Volume Master Key; those unlock methods instead are used to decrypt the VMK via what are called "key protectors" which are present in the metadata section of all Bitlocker volumes. Thus, even on multiple drives that have the same PIN/password, the protector would be different because the VMK that it's protecting is different.

Also, if the flashdrive is connected to the computer and its Bitlocker encryption is already "unlocked" (that is, the OS can access the encrypted volume), then the same attack would work fine on removable volumes as fixed ones. In fact, I'd be a little surprised if the tool as built is "smart" enough to reliably capture only the OS volume, rather than the first Bitlocker key that happens to be retrieved from the TPM.

---

The attack you read about - sniffing the Bitlocker key by tapping the memory connection on the motherboard - is basically a non-story. Everybody in the industry knew it was possible, with hardware access, to extract an encryption key if it's present in the machine in main memory (one could in theory perform both the key decoding and the decryption entirely within the TPM, sending in ciphertext and getting back plain or vice versa, but this would probably impose an unacceptable performance overhead... or maybe not; I haven't actually checked). The fact that the guy targeted a foolishly exposed connector found on certain laptop models from a company that really has abused and tarnished its old reputation for security these days is modestly interesting, but the standard approaches - either tapping the RAM pins or freezing the RAM and physically pulling it - were already known to work. In fact, on modern CPUs where the only TPM in the system is usually the one integral to the CPU, this would be far less viable than the known attacks. Even the bit about using a Raspberry Pi is unsurprising, since all that was needed was a minimal microprocessor to read and decode the data on the pins. Even an RPi Pico is vastly more compute hardware than is actually necessary to carry out the attack; it's just a convenient amount of cheap computer to buy if, as in this case, you wanted to build a small custom single-board computer.

To be clear, props to the guy for building it; it's a cool project and getting the price down to ~$10 in hardware is in fact a little impressive. But it has almost no real-world security implications. It requires that the Bitlocker drive either already be unlocked or unlock automatically on boot (both of which are obviously and well-known to be less secure, and therefore less interesting scenarios), and an attacker who has enough hardware access to physically take your specific-models-of-laptop apart could use already-known attacks on basically any Windows PC.